# Reshape Pandas dataframe (partial transpose)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a csv similar to the following, where the column heading specifies the time (hour number):

```
Day,Location,1,2,3
1/1/2021,A,0.26,0.25,0.49
1/1/2021,B,0.8,0.23,0.55
1/1/2021,C,0.32,0.11,0.58
1/2/2021,A,0.67,0.72,0.49
1/2/2021,B,0.25,0.09,0.56
1/2/2021,C,0.83,0.54,0.7
```

When I load it as a dataframe using

```
df = pd.read_csv(open('VirusLevels.csv', 'r'), index_col=[0,1], header=0)
```

Pandas creates a dataframe with indices Day and Location, and column names 1, 2, and 3.

I need it to be reshaped as shown below, where Day and Time are the indices, and the Location is the column heading:

[image]

I've tried a lot of things and followed a lot of rabbitholes, but haven't been successful.  The most on-point example I could find suggested something like the following, but it doesn't work (says "KeyError: 'Day'").

```
df.melt(id_vars=['Day'], var_name= 'Time', 
        value_name = 'VirusLevels').sort_values(by='Location').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For posterity, it would help if you posted the contents of this CSV file, not an image of it.

Comment: I tried, but couldn't see a way.  Help please!

Comment: can you copy and paste the raw text file (i.e., open it with notepad or some other text editor)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  If there's a better way of formatting that, please let me know or feel free to tweak.  Thanks again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('VirusLevels.csv', index_col=[0,1])
df.rename_axis(columns='Time').stack().unstack('Location')

# or
# df.rename_axis('Time',axis='columns').stack().unstack('Location')
```

Output:

```
Location              A         B         C
Day      Time                              
1/1/2021 1     0.345307  0.099403  0.474077
         2     0.299947  0.853091  0.352472
         3     0.400975  0.599249  0.743099
1/2/2021 1     0.660258  0.003976  0.295406
         2     0.425434  0.953433  0.418783
         3     0.421021  0.844761  0.369561
```

Comment: For some reason I get the following error, although I see that "columns" is a legit keword argument for df.rename_axis method.  Not sure why:  TypeError: rename_axis() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Comment: So I did the following and it worked. df = df_raw.rename_axis('Time',axis='columns').stack().unstack('Location')

Comment: FYI, I think you should get the credit (you basically got me there, and just had to tweak the arguments).  But I also don't want to mark it as the answer if I'm not sure that your particular syntax works.  So if you edit to the answer that worked for me, I'll mark your answer as the answer.